# Maximise this sum of sines

Tags: lagrange-multiplier

> Let $n\in\Bbb N,n\ge2$. Find the maximum of 
>   $$f:[0,\pi]^n\to\Bbb R$$
>   $$f(x_1,...,x_n):=\sum_{i=1}^n\sin(x_i)$$
>   with the constraint: $\sum_{i=1}^n x_i=2\pi$

My attempt:

Let $g(x_1,...,x_n):=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i$

I need to find components $c_1,...,c_n:=c$ such that $\nabla f(c)=\lambda \nabla g(c)$

$$\nabla f(c)=\bigl(\cos(c_1),...,\cos(c_n)\bigr)$$
$$\nabla g(c) =(c_1,...,c_n)$$

I end up with this system of equations
$$\cos(c_j)=\lambda c_j \; \;j=1,...,n $$

And I am stuck here, how should I proceed?

Comment: Jensen's inequality might be of use here: for any $x_1, \ldots, x_n \in [0, \pi]$: $$\frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n \sin x_i \leqslant \sin \left( \frac{1}{n} \sum_{i=1}^n x_i \right)$$ since $\sin$ is concave on $[0, \pi]$.

Comment: You miscomputed $\nabla g$. Actually, $\nabla g(x) = (1,\dotsc,1)$ for all $x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are maximizing a function you are looking for

$$ [\nabla \cdot f](\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0} $$

when you are maximizing a function within a finite subset of the definition space $[0,\pi]^n$ you must both look for all points with $[\nabla \cdot f](\mathbf{x}) = \mathbf{0}$ and compare with the maximums along the border of the search subset. In your case you have a taxi cab norm $n-1$ sphere centered at the origin.

So first solving for

$$ [\nabla \cdot f](\mathbf{x}) = (cos(x_1),\dots,cos(x_n))^T = \mathbf{0} \leftrightarrow x_i = (2n_i+1) \frac{\pi}{2} \forall i\in[1,n]$$

so you have one extreme point inside your definition interval, $x_i = \frac{\pi}{2}$. The border of your search interval is a hyper-plane of dimension $n-1$, but since $sin$ is concave (as [Adayah](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/149178/adayah) pointed out) on the interval you know that if the extreme value you found is outside the border: the best value will be ON the border. (it is easy to show that this extreme value is a maximum by the second derivative) If it is inside the border: the highest value is already found as all other values will be smaller. If it is on the border you are also done as all other values will be smaller.

I will leave the rest to you!

If you are interested in taxi cab metrics here is a circle :P

[image: Taxi cab norm]